# Find the maximum values in nth column for each distinct values in 1st column in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a 3 column file and I want to find the maximum value of the third column with rows with same first column and have also the second column in output.

Input:

```
1   234   0.005
1   235   0.060
1   236   0.001
2   234   0.010
2   235   0.003
2   236   0.003
3   234   0.004
3   235   0.100
3   236   0.004
```

Desired output:

```
1   235   0.060
2   234   0.010
3   235   0.100
```

I found this hint from previous questions but I do not know how to have also the second column:

```
!($1 in max) || $3>max[$1] { max[$1] = $3 }
END {
     PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
     for (key in max) {
         print key, max[key]
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk '!($1 in max) || $3 > max[$1] { max[$1] = $3; two[$1] = $2 }
END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
   for (i in max) print i, two[i], max[i]
}' file
```

```
1 235 0.060
2 234 0.010
3 235 0.100
```

Comment: I think it's still nice to include the `!($1 in max)` in case all of the `$3` values are negative.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for the helping. what about having two maximum for specific number in the first column? for instance, [[1,234,0.060],[1,235,0.060],[1,236,0.010]]. How can I do an average over the second column having maximum value in the third column.

Comment: @Raha: That is a different problem not specified in your question and that would require significant changes in answer. I suggest asking a new question for that.

Comment: @anubhava Ok, I will do that. Thanks!

Comment: @Raha: You may try: `awk '!($1 in max) || $3 >= max[$1] { if (max[$1] == $3 ) { c[$1]++; two[$1] += $2 } else two[$1] = $2; max[$1] = $3 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"; for (i in max) print i, two[i] / (c[i] + 1), max[i] }' file`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sort -k1n -k3nr file | uniq -w 1
1   235   0.060
2   234   0.010
3   235   0.100
```

Use `sort` to sort on fields 1 and 3, 3 reversed. Then use `uniq` and compare only 1st char.

Another one using GNU awk:

```
$ awk '{
    a[$1][$3]=$0 }
END {   
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"       # first for in ascending order
    for(i in a) {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"  # next for in descending
        for(j in a[i]) {
            print a[i][j]
            break
        }
    }
}' file
1   235   0.060
2   234   0.010
3   235   0.100
```

Comment: This is making the assumption that the first field is only a single character.  Adjusting the pipe from a `uniq` to `awk '!x[$1]++'` will work if the first field is longer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `-w` option on `uniq` is a GNUism, and doesn't exist in most other implementations.

Comment: @ghoti Could be but for example FreeBSD has `uniq -s` which seems equivalent. Unfortunately (sigh) I recycled my last Sun years ago.

Comment: @borrible True, but it should be ok to increase the value of `-w` before it reaches second the field, right?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.  It should give the output in same order of Input_file's input sequence.

```
awk '
!a[$1]++{
  b[++count]=$1
}
{
  c[$1]=(c[$1]>$NF?c[$1]:$NF)
  d[$1]=(c[$1]>$NF?d[$1]:$1 OFS $2)
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print d[b[i]],c[b[i]]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1 235 0.060
2 234 0.010
3 235 0.100
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too here.

```
awk '
!a[$1]++{                              ##Checking condition if array named a has NO occurrence of $1 in it then do following.
  b[++count]=$1                        ##Create array b whose index is variable count with increasing value of 1 each time value is $1 for it.
}
{
  c[$1]=(c[$1]>$NF?c[$1]:$NF)          ##Creating array c value index is $1 and checking if $NF value is greater then its value then change it to $NF else no change.
  d[$1]=(c[$1]>$NF?d[$1]:$1 OFS $2)    ##Creating array d value index is $1 and checking if $NF value is greater then its value then change it to $NF else no change.
}
END{                                   ##Starting end block of awk program here.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){               ##Starting for loop here from i value 1 to till value of count.
    print d[b[i]],c[b[i]]              ##Printing value of array d whose index is value of b[i] and array c whose index is b[i].
  }
}' Input_file                          ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in any modern awk (not just GNU):

```
$ awk '!a[$1]||$3>b[$1]{a[$1]=$0;b[$1]=$3} END {for(i in a)print a[i]}' file | sort -n
```

Broken out for easier reading:

- `!a[$1] || $3>b[$1]` - If we haven't seen the first column before OR the third column beats our previous record,
- `{a[$1]=$0;b[$1]=$3}` - then store the current line in one array, and the comparison value in another array.
- `END {for(i in a)print a[i]}` - Once we've processed all the input, print each line from our storage array.
- `sort -n` - sort numerically. Should work with any sort of `sort`.

Clear as mud?

This solution notably stores entire lines (`$0`) rather than the content of individual fields, so its output will *be* the input lines, rather than *recreate* the input lines. This might be useful if you're comfortable with default field splitting for the sake of collecting fields for comparison, but you have columnated or tabbed input that you want your output to match.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sort -k1,1n -k3,3nr file | awk '!seen[$1]++'
1   235   0.060
2   234   0.010
3   235   0.100
```

Comment: Indeed, that was the case!