# Bash: find the maximum of the nth column with conditions on the other columns

Tags: awk

I have a bog file with 3 columns and I want to find the maximum of the third column and write the entire row when they have the same first column. I have already ask my question but the problem now is that I have more than one row with the maximum number. Now, I want to choose that one has the highest value in the second column!

[My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446221/find-the-maximum-values-in-nth-column-for-each-distinct-values-in-1st-column-in)

My data:

```
    1 234 0.01
    1 235 0.05
    1 236 0.05
    1 237 0.02
    2 234 0.09
    2 235 0.09
    2 236 0.08
    2 237 0.05
```

Output:

```
    1 236 0.05
    2 235 0.09
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solution 1st:*** Could you please try following. This will take care of order of the first field's value as per Input_file.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  b[$1]=a[$1]>$3?b[$1]:$0
  a[$1]=a[$1]>$3?a[$1]:$3
  next
}
($1 in a){
  print b[$1]
  delete a[$1]
}
'   Input_file  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you don't care about the order of `$1`(first field) in output.

```
awk '{b[$1]=a[$1]>$3?b[$1]:$0;a[$1]=a[$1]>$3?a[$1]:$3} END{for(i in a){print b[i]}}' Input_file
```

Comment: Both work perfectly! Why should I put two time inputfile? It does not work if I put one time input.

Answer (score 0):

Using shell tools:

```
$ sort -k3nr -k2nr file | uniq -w 5
    2 235 0.09
    1 236 0.05
```

It works if your first column can match to a certain number of characters. `man uniq`:

```
-w, --check-chars=N
       compare no more than N characters in lines
```

It works for fixed width first column, like:

```
1    Second column
1000 Second column
```

but not:

```
1 Second
1000 Second
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works for the sample data but it seems not to work for a very large data file (my real data set). The number of the rows with the same first column is 10000, should I put 10001 instead of 5? The output is not sorted too.

Comment: No, the N value is the length of the first column. It expects fixed width for the first column.